# How to connect pyspark to HiveThriftServer2?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to connect my spark application with the thriftserver started with start-thriftserver.sh, but I always get a TTransportException. I am using Spark 3.3.0.
Connecting to the thriftserver via Beeline works without a problem.

I am trying to connect to the metastore by launching pyspark with the command

```
pyspark \
--conf spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:10000 \
--conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=maven \
--conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=2.3.9
```

To test the connection I run SHOW TABLES.

```
spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").show()
```

This results in the following TTransportException.

```
WARN HiveClientImpl: HiveClient got thrift exception, destroying client and retrying (0 tries remaining)
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.databaseExists(Hive.java:1552)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v0_12.databaseExists(HiveShim.scala:609)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:394)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.$anonfun$withHiveState$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:274)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.databaseExists(HiveClientImpl.scala:394)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:223)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager(SharedState.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$2(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager(SessionCatalog.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listTables(SessionCatalog.scala:1031)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listTables(SessionCatalog.scala:1017)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.listTables(SessionCatalog.scala:1009)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2SessionCatalog.listTables(V2SessionCatalog.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.ShowTablesExec.run(ShowTablesExec.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result$lzycompute(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.result(V2CommandExec.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2CommandExec.executeCollect(V2CommandExec.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:220)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:622)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:617)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_database(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:782)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_database(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:769)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getDatabase(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1288)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2327)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1563)
        ... 67 more
22/10/25 14:25:32 WARN HiveClientImpl: Deadline exceeded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 1034, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

What is the correct way to connect spark to the metastore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, for anyone who has the same problem:
There are multiple kinds of thrift servers.
The one set by spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris is a thrift server for the metastore. This can, for example, be a hive metastore standalone server.

The server startet with start-thriftserver.sh is for connecting via jdbc and is not a metastore thrift server.

To have pyspark and jdbc use the same metastore, both pyspark and start-thriftserver.sh need to access the same metastore by setting spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.uris.